# Android - GreenDroid and googleapis

Tags: android, google-maps, greendroid

I have used GreenDroid library in my application. There is no error on compilation (building). When I run this application on emulator it shows this error in console as

```
[2013-02-13 18:10:08 - GreenDroid] Could not find GreenDroid.apk!

[2013-02-13 18:10:08 - GreenDroid-GoogleAPIs] Could not find GreenDroid-GoogleAPIs.apk!
```

And in log cat error

```
02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.cyrilmottier.android.greendroid.R$layout

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at greendroid.app.GDActivity.createLayout(GDActivity.java:177)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at greendroid.app.GDActivity.ensureLayout(GDActivity.java:187)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at greendroid.app.GDActivity.getActionBar(GDActivity.java:265)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.singaporegp.f1.home.F1_Splash.onCreate(F1_Splash.java:41)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

02-13 18:10:17.115: E/AndroidRuntime(421):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to try in order:

Check the project is not set as a library:
Go to Project->Properties
Select Android from left-hand side list
Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox
Clean and rebuild the project - this should delete and recreate the entire gen folder, including the R.java file mentioned in some peoples answers
Check eclipse and all the Android plugins are up to date
Close the project, exit Eclipse, reopen eclipse, reopen the project.
Go to Java Build Path > Projects and check for any incorrect project dependencies
Go to the main preferences for Eclipse and under Android->Build uncheck 'Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch'